# Wordpress: Array OUTPUT in order

Tags: php, wordpress

in wordpress i have a query where it queries specific posts.

```
<div id="container-">   
<?php
query_posts( array( 'post__in' => array( 53,51,46,44,42,40,34,30,28) ) );
$divname=1;
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>
<div id="outdiv<?php echo $divname ?>">
    <div id="div<?php echo $divname ?>">
        <?php the_content();?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
$divname ++;
endwhile;
?>
</div>
```

I want it to output the post i want in order which is posts `53,51,46,44,42,40,34,30,28`
because it outputs randomly, the posts contains Images and text.
My question is, Can this be possible? or is it the `<?php the_content()?>` not giving the posts in proper order? Or The HTML? please help?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
query_posts( array( 'post__in' => array( 53,51,46,44,42,40,34,30,28), 
                    'orderby' => 'ID', 
                    'order' => 'DESC' ) );
```

MySQL does not care about an order of elements in IN statement of the query.

Comment: Thank you it worked, i altered some of it.but it worked fine.